# Помогите с рекурсивным алгоритмом на delphi. Признак делимости на 11

Tags: delphi, алгоритм, pascal, рекурсия

Основная проблема в том, что функция постоянно возвращает значение false, а такого не должно быть.
Вот код

```
//Функция, которая проверяет кратно ли число по признаку кратности на 11.
function isMultiple(x : integer) : boolean;
var nums : array [1..100] of integer;
    i, sum1, sum2, f : integer;
begin
result := false;
if (x >= 11) then
  begin
  i := 0;
  //Здесь проискодит разделение разрядов числа для последующего сложения
  while (x > 0) do
    begin
      nums [i] := x mod 10;
      inc (i);
      x := x div 10
    end;
  f := 2;
  sum1 := 0;
  sum2 := 0;
  //Здесь производится сложение чисел на четных и нечетных местах.
  while (f <= i) do
    begin
      sum1 := sum1 + nums[f - 1];
      sum2 := sum2 + nums[f];
      f := f + 2
    end;
  //Здесь сравниваются значения полученных сумм
  if (sum1 = sum2) then
    result := true
  else
    //Если суммы не равны, то вызываем опять функцию для проверки кратности на 11
    //разности этих сумм
    if (isMultiple(sum1 - sum2) = true) then
      result := true
    else
      result := false;
  end
  else
    result := false;
end;
```

Comment: Хотел бы спросить: а индексы для массивов в Delphi с 0 начинаются или с 1?

Comment: Вы опишите вербально ваш признак делимости на 11. Допустим (не помню как правильно звучит)  сумма цифр должна делится на 11.

Comment: Индекс начинается с [a..b]  из а, т.е. со скольки хотите. Данный пример в вопросе - с 1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы правы, в коде ошибка, массив задан с 1 `var nums : array [1..100]` но в первом же заходе `i := 0;  nums[i]=` тут возникает "неполадка" с памятью, т.е. программа может работать некорректно. Так как rangeCheckError по умолчанию выключено - предсказать поведение програмы сложно. Может "перетираться" соседняя переменная и вылазить весёлый "глюк"

Comment: а зачем у вас все выражения после if и while завернуты в () ? можно догадаться что c-style привычка, но стоило учитывать разницу языков и тогда бы может не было бы ошибки с индексами массива

Comment: Из всех пердложенных вариантов нет ни  одного верного, при последних изменениях у меня вообще начинается бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: Я вижу алгоритм другой, пока число >= 11, проверить суму чётных на совпадение с сумой нечётных, иначе сделать рекурсию на их разницу, главное первые с вторыми не перепутать. Возможно у вас перепутано и нужно поменять `sum1 - sum2` местами. Плюс **исправить ошибку** в массиве. И ещё вариант отрицательного числа при операции минус. Если я не правильно описал ваш алгоритм - опишите его в заголовке правильно.

Comment: Задание №1. **Исправить ошибку** в массиве. Поскольку адресация с нуля поставить `[0..100]`. До исправления этой ошибки исход программы непредсказуем - т.е. вполне возможны зависания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция некорректная. В этом цикле

```
 i := 0;
 ^^^^^^
 //Здесь проискодит разделение разрядов числа для последующего сложения

 while (x > 0) do
    begin
      nums [i] := x mod 10;
      inc (i);
      x := x div 10
    end;
```

Вы записываете значения в массив, начиная с элемента с индексом 0.

А в этом цикле

```
 f := 2;
 ^^^^^^^
  sum1 := 0;
  sum2 := 0;
  //Здесь производится сложение чисел на четных и нечетных местах.
  while (f <= i) do
    begin
      sum1 := sum1 + nums[f - 1];
      sum2 := sum2 + nums[f];
      f := f + 2
    end;
```

вы пропускаете элемент массива с индексом 0 так как выражение `f-1` при `f` равном 2 равно 1, и суммируете элементы, начиная с индекса 1.

Более того, если число элементов в массиве нечетное, то данное увеличение индекса

```
      f := f + 2
```

может привести к тому, что один элемент будет пропущен.

Вам надо организовать цикл очень просто

```
f := 1
while( f < i ) do
    begin
        if ( f mod 2 = 0 ) then
            sum1 := sum1 + nums[f];
        else
            sum2 := sum2 + nums[f];
        f := f + 1;
    end
```

Если индексы в массиве начинаются с 1, то и переменные `i` и `f` также должны быть инициализированы 1.

И, как подсказывает **nick_n_a**  вам следует передавать положительное значение в качестве аргумента функции при очередном рекурсивном вызове функции.
Поэтому в этом предложении вам следует использовать абсолютную величину разницы.

```
 if (isMultiple(sum1 - sum2) = true) then
```

Comment: И так, я изменил циклы, но ф-ия все равно работает неверно

Comment: @Ник Значит неправильно изменили. Только и всего. Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Т.е. до этого я делал программы с такой границой и все было хорошо, а теперь значит нет?

Comment: @Ник Вы должны определиться: то ли у вас индексы начинаются с 0, то ли с 1. А иначе программа не корректная. В моем ответе все написано.

Comment: Да, я сделал все как вы говорите, внес все изменения, и все равно бесконечный цикл

Comment: Ну конечно, в вашем цикле f не уменьшается, а остается всегда прежней

Comment: @Ник Это опечатка

Comment: Я заметил, спасибо большое. Задача решена.

Comment: @Ник Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Comment: Я не вижу учтения  случая когда sum1 - sum2 будет **меньше нуля**. А если так, можно подобрать пример на котором ваша программа даст ошибку (false вместо true). Такое может точно быть. Проверьте числа **143** и **341** оба делятся

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню, в Delphi есть оператор `mod`, возвращающий остаток от деления и который у вас используется.
Потому проверить кратность можно, например, проще, вот так:

```
//Делим число на 11 и смотрим, чему равен остаток от деления, если он 0 - число кратно.
if (N mod 11) = 0 then write(N,' кратно 11');
```

Comment: Неа, нужно именно по признаку делимости, тобишь через рекурсию

Comment: Так у вас всё равно используется `mod` в коде, для вычисления остатка от деления на 10.

Comment: Это что бы число в массив разбить

Comment: @Ник Опишите ваш признак вербально. В школе признак помнил конечно, сейчас не помню.

Comment: Что бы потом складывать числа на четных и нечетных позициях

Comment: Число делится на 11, если сумма его чисел на нечетных позициях = сумме чисел на четных, или отличается на число которое кратно 11

Comment: Хорошо, сложили, и если число более 10 повторить ещёраз, или как? Вы до конца опишите алгоритм. Не понятно зачем рекурсия, можно так пройти весь ряд.

Comment: Да, повторять, пока число больше 10

Comment: Нет, больше чем 10, поскольку 11 кратно 11, значит алгоритм должен проверять и 11

Answer (score 0):

Может вам таки попробовать без массивов? Попробую как-то так:

```
function isMultiple(x : integer) : boolean;     
 // Тут у вас ошибка №1 границы массива
 var  i, sum1, sum2, f : integer; 
begin
  result := false;
  if (x<0) x = -x; // учёл знак (тут у вас ошибка №2)
  if (x >= 11) then
    begin
    i := 0;
    //Здесь проискодит разделение разрядов числа для последующего сложения
    while (x > 0) do
    begin
      if i = 0 then sum1 :=   x mod 10 else  sum2 :=   x mod 10;
      inc (i);
      x := x div 10;
      if i=2 then i=0;
    end;
    if (sum1 = sum2)  result = true; else
    result := isMultiple(sum1 - sum2);          
 end;  
 end;
```